# Making an If Statement for first round of Switch Java

Tags: java, swing, switch-statement

Im trying to set a specific image for only the first iteration of a for loop through a switch. For `case 'f'` I would like to add a different image on the first iteration.

How would I do this? Is it even possible to keep track of within a switch?

```
    for (char c : symbols) {
            switch (c) {
            case 'X':
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.drawImage(wallImg, x, y, width, height, null);
                break;
            case 's':
                g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g2.drawImage(snakeImg, x, y, width, height, null);
                break;
            case 'f':
                g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                g2.drawImage(burgerImg, x, y, width, height, null);
                break;
            case '.':
                g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g2.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                break;
            case '\n':
                y += height;
            }
```

Comment: Add a boolean flag before the switch then do an if(boolean flag) check to see if it's true/false, then you go into the else if it's true so you can load a different image.

Comment: The iteration count should not be part of the painting process at all, since you cannot control how, if or when painting occurs. The change in object state should be in  your game loop (likely a Swing Timer).  The painting method should only *reflect* the state of the model, but not change it.

Comment: Did this solve your problem @user5402 you haven't marked it as a solution - what problem did you receive from it?

Comment: Thanks @Artemis, yes it solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a flag to see if you have iterated yet or not, then adopt an if statement into your switch-case to account for it like this:

```
        boolean flag = false;    

        for (char c : symbols) {
            switch (c) {
            case 'X':
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.drawImage(wallImg, x, y, width, height, null);
                break;
            case 's':
                g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g2.drawImage(snakeImg, x, y, width, height, null);
                break;
            case 'f':
                //check to see if your flag is true/false
                if(flag){
                    g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                    g2.drawImage(burgerImg, x, y, width, height, null);
                }else{
                    //set first image
                    flag = true;
                }
                break;
            case '.':
                g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g2.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                break;
            case '\n':
                y += height;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't the flag always be false though @Artemis?

Comment: @user5402 no because you set `flag = true` in the else statement and never set it back to false

Comment: Why are you using `Boolean flag` (capital **B**) rather than `boolean flag` (lowercase **b**) ?

Comment: I missed that, my mistake (though both work, but I should've used the primitive type not the object/reference type).